# How do i sort/order the Elements according to an attribute?

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I'm trying to order some XML elements by an attribute given inside that element.. here's an example.

I would like it to be like this.. as shown in below (example)

```
<root>
  <firstTemplate name="someTestName" id="123123">
   <element1>
       <element2Name1 value="123" value2="324" value3="412" position="1"/>
       <element2Name2 value="465" value2="552" value3="785" position="2"/>
       <element2Name3 value="378" value2="857" value3="457" position="3"/>
   </element1>
  </firstTemplate>
</root>
```

but when i completely parse the Xml with my program created on .net vb - visual basic, using XmlSerializer..

```
<root>
  <firstTemplate name="someTestName" id="123123">
   <element1>
       <element2Name2 value="123" value2="324" value3="412" position="2"/>
       <element2Name1 value="772" value2="423" value3="331" position="1"/>
       <element2Name3 value="432" value2="213" value3="775" position="3"/>
   </element1>
  </firstTemplate>
</root>
```

I would like it to be ordered according to that attribute (position) .. from 1 to 3 or more....  I've tried looking everywhere and alot of questions aswell. so i decided to make my first question here.. :) .

EDIT:

```
Public Sub Start()

     Dim clientInfoSerializer As New XmlSerializer(GetType(client_infos))

     Dim TemplateWriter As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Templates))

     Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\Parsed\templates.xml")

     ''File Reader
     Dim fileReader As New StreamReader(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + "\client_infos.xml")

     ''Loading files
     Dim Out As client_infos = CType(clientInfoSerializer.Deserialize(fileReader), client_infos)


     Dim temp as new Templates

     For Each template in Out.temps

         ''Here adds the required elements and attributes to temp varaible..


     Next



     TemplateWriter.Serialize(Writer, temp)

     Writer.close()
     fileReader.close()


EndSub
```

---

Here are the Classes

```
<XmlRoot("root")>
Public Class Templates

    <XmlElement("firstTemplate")>
    Public firstTemp as new List(Of Template)

End Class

Public Class Template

    <XmlAttribute>
    Public name as string

    <XmlAttribute>
    Public id as string

    <XmlElement("element1")>
    Public element1 as new List(Of elementTypes)

End Class


Public Class elementTypes

    ''inside these Type1,Type2, there are just some attributes and elements, Including position attribute (as a seperate abstract class, that inherits all)
    ''Possible that element2Name3 also might get position="1".. in that case element2Name3 must be at top (order first..) , so it depends on the position attribute..
    <XmlElement> Public element2Name1 as New List(Of Type1)
    <XmlElement> Public element2Name2 as New List(Of Type2)
    <XmlElement> Public element2Name3 as New List(Of Type3)
    <XmlElement> Public element2Name4 as New List(Of type4)
    <XmlElement> Public element2Name5 as New List(Of type5)

End Class
```

PS:Its a really long program, so i tried my best to shrink it in, and show the common part of the code, and i guess thats the part you asked for? ..

Thanks

Comment: Post your code for doing the serialization.

Comment: `XmlSerializer` will serialize by looping your `element1` collection. I think sorting your collection by `position` before serializing will help. If `element1` isn't collection then specify `<XmlElement(Order = 1)>` attribute for properties `element2Name1`, `element2Name2`

Comment: You mean adding the properties, Order for <element2Name1 ,element2Name2 and element2Name3? i've tried adding it, and im getting an error about reflecting type,  Right now, its being ordered according to how i've placed the variables in the class right?

`Public class elements
<XmlElement(Order:=1)> Public element2Name1 As New List(Of ExampleOfClass1)
    <XmlElement(Order:=1)> Public element2Name2 As New List(Of ExampleOfClass2)
    <XmlElement(Order:=1)> Public element2Name3 As New List(Of ExampleOfClass3)`

is there a way to ignore this order, and use the order as i add into the <element1> ?

Comment: @Fabio how do I sort them before serialising. .is it possible? Cus when I serialize it the order is being taken as I've wrote above..

Comment: _Show your code for doing serialization_

Comment: @Fabio i've added the code

Comment: @Tim added code for doing serialization